# Google Cloud Functions Gen 1 - HTTP trigger - NodeJS - promises - unhandled rejections

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions

Question about handling promises in HTTP triggered CLoud Functions for GCP. Especially gen1

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_not_start_background_activities

There's this note
"Note: If a Node.js event-driven function returns a Promise, Cloud Functions ensures that the Promise is settled before terminating."

So let's take a look at this example

```
const promise1 = new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        doSomething()
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
});
const promise2 = Promise.reject(new Error('insta rejection'));
try {
    await Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
} catch (e) {
    res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json(error.message);
}
```

As you can see, we have rejection, and on rejection we are sending status. Fail fast.
But there's still another promise going on, that might do everything, http connection, db connection, anything. It can also reject!

Once we send response, function is going into 'idle' state and is ready to be served for next requests. Idle means that CPU and RAM might be taken as far as I know.

Does anyone have some experience in that? How one should properly design HTTP function if those have a lot of async processing while not risking for 'leaking' promises after sending response

Comment: I am not sure if i understand the question here. `Promise.all()` rejects all promises as soon as one is rejected. If you want to stop all promises as soon as one promise sends response, you can use event listeners with custom events i guess.

Comment: @Cerlin yeah, it rejects asap. But that's the problem. It does not stop processing of other promises that were given into it. And that's the whole issue I find. Google suggest to stop all other tasks but with Promise.all[] it's hard. So I wonder about other ways of handling in parallel many promises and yet being safe with closing all tasks that might not be closed before function CPU is taken

Comment: Use `Promise.allSettled()`.